# How many transpositions of 2 are needed to replicate all permutations of 5?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a list {1,2,3,4,5}. There are 5!=120 permutations of {1,2,3,4,5}. Every permutation can be written as the product of cycles ("factors"), for instance the permutation {1,2,3,4,5}→{2,1,3,5,4} can be written (1,2)(3)(4,5). This is typically written as (1,2)(4,5), the product of two **interchanges**. Thus this particular permutation requires 2 element interchanges. All permutations are computed from the identity permutation {1,2,3,4,5}, in other words going from one permutation to another is not legal.

Question: If we wrote out all 120 permutations as such cycles, in total **how many interchanges of two would we find**?

Edit: I did some programming and simulated this question. I found that 326 transpositions are required. If anybody has the analytical answer to this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: like permuting $1$ with $2$, $1$ with $3$, $1$ with $4$, and $1$ with $5$?  (or $1$ with $2$, $2$ with $3$, $3$ with $4$, and $4$ with $5$?)  cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Generators_and_relations) Wikipedia information

Comment: "*how many permutations of 2*"  I don't understand what you mean by this.  Are you perhaps asking for a minimal set of transpositions which generate the group $S_5$?

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I think OP indeed means a $2$-cycle; cf. OP's usage of "permutations of $5$"

Comment: This question is poorly posed.  I *think* the OP is asking:  There are $120$ permutations of $\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$.  Every permutation can be written as the product of cycles ("factors"), for instance the permutation $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \to \{ 2,1,3,5,4 \}$ can be written $(1,2)(3)(4,5)$.  This is typically written as $(1,2)(4,5)$... the product of two interchanges.  Thus this particular permutation requires ***2*** element interchanges.  ***Q***:  If we wrote out all 120 permutations as such cycles, in total how many interchanges of two would we find?  (These are sometimes called permutation factors.)

Comment: @JanMarxen:  What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Exactly my question. Let me edit. Thank you

Comment: A broad hint: do you know any ways of building up all the permutations of 5 elements from the permutations of four elements? Can you show that any of them lead to a minimal number of interchanges?

Comment: The example in the question is badly chosen, since it only involves _adjacent_ transpositions (of 1,2 respectively 4,5). It is not clear if that is a requirement, or that you allow also transposing elements further apart. In particular, do you count the reversing permutation $1,2,3,4,5\to5,4,3,2,1$ for $2$ transpositions $(1,5)(2,4)(3)$ or as $10$: $(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(3,4)(2,3)(1,2)(4,5)(3,4)(2,3)(1,2)$? The question seems harder for the first way of counting. Even just a $5$-cycle $1,2,3,4,5\to2,3,4,5,1$ counts as how many transpositions?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That would generally be written as four transpositions; AFAIK there's no way of writing it with fewer, but it can be obtained as, for instance, the (left to right — sorry!) product (1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, 5). (And the way I've written it is a further hint in the direction of my previous one...)

Comment: (Although now that I write that, I realize that this is probably _NOT_ what OP was asking, given the clarifying comments; instead, I'm pretty sure they're looking specifically for the number of interchanges across 'minimal' cycle notation, i.e. (half of) the number of elements fixed by $\mathcal{p}^2$ but not by $\mathcal{p}$, summed over all permutations $\mathcal{p}$.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeewen For example, { 5, 1, 4, 3, 2 } -> (5, 1, 2)(4, 3). What is the minimum number of transpositions in 120 of these 5 element permutations?

Comment: @JanMarxen There are two very different statistics on the group of permutations of $n$: the minimum number of _adjecent_ transpositions needed to write the permutation as their product (the Coxeter length, this is also the number of inversions: pairs of indices $i<j$ such that $p(i)>p(j)$) which runs from $0$ to $\frac{n(n-1)}2$) and the minimum number of general transpositions needed (this is $n$ minus the number of disjoint cycles $p$ can be decomposed into, since every cycle of length $l$ can be written as product of $l-1$ transpositions) running from $0$ to $n-1$. Please say __which__ one.

Comment: @MarcvanLeewen I did not ask how many adjacent transpositions are required, I just asked how many general transpositions are required. So a cycle of length n has n-1 general transpositions and adjacent transpositions are not supposed to be the topic. So no, I am not talking about the Coxeter length, I am talking about general transpositions.

Comment: @marx just to make it clear: you want to count three transpositions in the permutation $(5 1 2) (4 3)$, not 1 or some other number?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki There are 3 total transpositions in (512)(43).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to the problem, based (loosely) on generating functions. First of all, note that all the permutations of a set of $n$ elements can be obtained by starting with all the permutations of a set of $n-1$ elements, placing the new element at the end of each permutation, and then swapping it with the element at position $i$ for $i=1\ldots n$ (note that the last 'swap' here is just swapping it with itself; this essentially corresponds to just appending $(n)$ to the cycle notation for the previous permutation). (The $n$ possible swaps for the new element mean that the total number of permutations, $P_n$, satisfies $P_n=n\cdot P_{n-1}$, giving $P_n=n!$, just as you'd expect.)  Now, when we generate our new permutations this way, there are two distinct ways that we can get a two-cycle. Either it can exist in the 'parent' permutation, and then the new element has to be swapped with something other than it; or it can involve the new element swapping with an element in the parent permutation that was fixed by the parent permutation.  Since there's some dependency among these items, I'm going to write $p_{i,j;n}$ for the number of permutations of $n$ things with $i$ fixed points and $j$ two-cycles.

Now, let's consider the ways in which the new element corresponding to $n$ can be inserted into a permutation that's a member of $p_{i,j;n-1}$. It can be a new fixed point; this creates a permutation in $p_{(i+1),j;n}$. It can swap with one of the $i$ fixed points of the permutation, creating $i$ different permutations in $p_{i-1,j+1;n}$. Or it can swap with one of the $2j$ elements that was in a two-cycle in the previous permutation, creating $2j$ different permutations in $p_{i,j-1;n}$. Or it can swap with one of the $n-(i+2j+1)$ elements that's in a longer cycle, in which case neither $i$ nor $j$ change and we have $n-(i+2j+1)$ new permutations in $p_{i,j;n}$.

Now, we can 'reverse-engineer' this: if we have a permutation in $p_{i,j;n}$, then there's one way it could have come from a permutation in $p_{i-1,j;n-1}$. There are $(i+1)$ ways it could have come from a permutation in $p_{i+1,j-1;n-1}$. There are $(2j+2)$ ways it could have come from a permutation in $p_{i,j+1;n-1}$.  And there are $n-(i+2j+1)$ ways it could have come from a permutation in $p_{i,j;n-1}$.  In other words, we have the recurrence relation:

$$p_{i,j;n} = p_{i-1,j;n-1}+(i+1)p_{i+1,j-1;n-1}+(2j+2)p_{i,j+1;n-1}+(n-(i+2j+1))p_{i,j;n-1}$$

Now, if we imagine writing the polynomial $p_n(s,t)=\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j;n}s^it^j$, then the coefficients in the recurrence relation can be broken down as follows: $p_{i-1,j;n-1}s^it^j$ corresponds to a term $sp_{n-1}(s,t)$ (since it's $s\cdot p_{i-1, j;n-1}s^{i-1}t^j$ and we can renumber the indices). Similarly, the term $(i+1)p_{i+1,j-1;n-1} s^it^j$ corresponds to a term $t\frac{\partial}{\partial s}p_{n-1}(s,t)$; applying the (partial) derivative accounts for the presence of $i+1$, and multiplying by $t$ shifts the $j$-index. Likewise, the $(2j+2)p_{i,j+1;n-1}s^it^j$ term corresponds to a term $2\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_{n-1}(s,t)$.

Finally, there's the term $n-(i+2j+1)p_{i,j;n-1}$. I'll write this as $(n-1)p_{i,j;n-1}-ip_{i,j;n-1}-2jp_{i,j;n-1}$.  Similarly to the above, these terms correspond to $(n-1)p_{n-1}(i,j)$, $-s\frac{\partial}{\partial s}p_{n-1}(s,t)$; and $-2t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_{n-1}(s,t)$. Putting this all together, we have the following polynomial recurrence relation for a partial generating function of the coefficients:

$$p_n(s,t) = sp_{n-1}(s,t)+t\frac{\partial}{\partial s}p_{n-1}(s,t) + 2\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_{n-1}(s,t)+(n-1)p_{n-1}(s,t)-s\frac{\partial}{\partial s}p_{n-1}(s,t)-2t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_{n-1}(s,t)$$

Or, combining terms,
$$p_n(s,t) = (s+n-1)p_{n-1}(s,t)+(t-s)\frac{\partial}{\partial s}p_{n-1}(s,t) + (2-2t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_{n-1}(s,t)$$.

Now, you could go a step further than this, and obtain an overall generating function $\mathcal{P}(x;s,t) = \sum_n x^np_n(s,t)$, and get a differential equation for $\mathcal{P}$ relating the partial derivative in $x$ to the other partial derivatives by using the same sort of operations again. This leads to a pretty messy differential equation, and you'll likely need to take much more care with boundary conditions. Still, this approach should in theory get towards the destination.

Finally, once this is together, then the quantity you're interested in, the total number of interchanges among all length n permutations, is $\mathcal{I}_n = \sum_i\sum_j 2jp_{i,j;n}$. In terms of the generating function, this is essentially $2(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(s,t)|_{(s,t)=(1,1)})-2p(1,1)$ where the notation in the first term means 'compute the partial derivative as a function, then evaluate it at $s=1,t=1$'.

Comment: Is the previous permutation n-1 simply a list with less one element? So if we are talking about the list [1,2,3,4,5] it would have to be [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: @Marx The previous permutation specifically here is the one that generates the 'new' permutation via the process I describe at the start of this. So if, for instance, the new permutation is $1\mapsto 3, 2\mapsto 2, 3\mapsto 5, 4\mapsto 1, 5\mapsto 4$ — or, in cycle notation, $(1 3 5 4)(2)$ — then the previous permutation would be $1\mapsto 3, 2\mapsto 2, 3\mapsto 4, 4 \mapsto 1$; in cycle notation, $(1 3 4)(2)$.

Comment: I like your idea very much, but I am asking for the number of transposition when all permutations work independently from each other. So one permutation cannot be generated by the last one, nor can more than one permutation be generated from the same "parent" permutation.